# Tem algum problema em usar 2 handler.postDelay() ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: android, handler

Gostaria de saber se existe algum problema com a performance do App em usar 2 `handler.postDlay()` ao mesmo tempo, tipo chamando as 2 em funções: dentro do OnCreate Td1(); Td2();

```
public void Td1(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {



            handler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 1000);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);

}

public void Td2(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {



            handler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 1000);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai depender do que os métodos `run()` fizerem.

Lembre que o método `run()` vai ser executado na *thread* onde foi criado o *handler*, neste caso na *UIThread*.

Tenha também em conta que sendo os argumentos passados ao *postDelay* iguais e os métodos `Td1()` e `Td2()` chamados um a seguir ao outro, é praticamente o mesmo que ter apenas um *postDelay* que execute o conteúdo  de cada um dos métodos `run()`, um a seguir ao outro.

Suponha que são agendadas as tarefas 1 e 2, uma em cada *postDelay*:

```
public void Td1(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            tarefa_1();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 1000);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);

}

public void Td2(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            tarefa_2();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 1000);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);

}
```

chamar `Td1();` e de seguida `Td2();` é o mesmo que ter apenas um método(Td3) que agende as duas tarefas:

```
public void Td3(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            tarefa_1();
            tarefa_2();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 1000);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);

}
```

e chamar só `Td3();`

Comment: então no caso eu deveria usar tudo em uma unica tread?

Comment: Não confunda thread com handler.

Comment: certo, mas nesse caso, eu poderia colocar todas as ações dentro de uma só, sou posso usar dividido em 2, essa é minha duvida!

Comment: Você pode por em uma ou duas, o que eu tentei explicar é se chamar os métodos Td1 e Td2 um a seguir ao outro é o mesmos que chamar um com todas as acções.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!